# How to check write permission using CHMOD (numeric)?

Tags: chmod

How to check write permission when i have for example 0755 ? I cant use "-rw" etc. I need it for my perl script (homework).

Comment: are you asking how to determine what the write permissions are from the number 0755?

Comment: ok, i made it. i'm checking by regexp /.[^5410]../

Comment: Checking an regexp to determinate permission is very very bad idea! You should use system function and aPI to do this.

Comment: oh come on... it works very good! and its very simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That octal number number translates to

```
7   5   5           # octal
111 101 101         # binary
rwx r-x r-x         # permissions for owner, group and others
```

Hope this helps. You should be able to isolate the bit you are interested in and check if it is set, aren't you?